# Python: populate list in dictionary from data in excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to take the below data from excel sheet and create a dictionary with a list of mac address values in this format siteinv_dict = {1741 : [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY]}
The list of mac addresses vary from col to col.

[image]

When trying to do it for just one number to try get it working i was trying something like this and failed but really i would like it to get each header number make it the key then list of mac addresses as values

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Site_Details.xlsx', data_only=True)
sh = wb.active

siteno = "1741"
siteinv_dict = {}

for row in sh.rows:
    if row[3].value == "1741":
        for i in range(4):
            siteinv_dict ={siteno : [ ]}
```

Comment: Do you know that the headings always start in row 2 column G. Do you know how many columns contain significant data?

Comment: No, The headings will always be a number. The number is an identifier used for each site. 
So this is all part of a using an API to create a site and assign inventory to it depending on the data in the excel sheet. 
Else where on the sheet each store to be created is listed and site identifier used so I can count how many sites to be created and then ill know how many columns there will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a deque by column of the workbook, then left pop everything off the deque using non-strings as keys and strings as a values list into a new dict.

```
import openpyxl
from collections import deque

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Site_Details.xlsx', data_only=True)
sh = wb.active

siteinv_queue = deque([cell.value for col in sh.iter_cols() for cell in col if cell.value is not None])
siteinv_dict = {}

k = siteinv_queue.popleft()
v = []
while siteinv_queue:
    item = siteinv_queue.popleft()
    if isinstance(item, str):
        v.append(item)
    else:
        siteinv_dict.update({k:v})
        k, v = item, []             
siteinv_dict.update({k:v}) # don't forget the last dict

print(siteinv_dict)
```

Output

```
{1741: ['xx:xx:xx:f0:9b:3f', 'xx:xx:xx:f0:5b:3f', 'xx:xx:xx:f0:4b:3f', 'xx:xx:xx:f0:3b:3f'], 250: ['yy:yy:yy:f0:9b:3f', 'yy:yy:yy:f0:9b:4f'], 731: ['zz:zz:zz:zz:2a:23:12', 'zz:zz:zz:zz:2a:23:13', 'zz:zz:zz:zz:2a:23:14']}
```

Comment: is there a way to specify the column to start from?  
in my excel sheet columns A-E already have other data.

Comment: update the list comprehension above to be `sh.iter_cols(7)` - ie insert `7`

Comment: Thank you, that does what i need.  Wish i understood how it did :-) but gets the job done.